# Cython: calling modules from other modules

Tags: python, cython

I am attempting to wrap a fairly large project with cython, and I am a little confused how to make sure I don't get the heirarchy messed up...

For example, lets say I have an A.pxi file located in

> /Project/Globals/A.pxi

and I have another file B.pxi that is dependent on A, and that is located at

> Project/Utilities/B.pxi

So I thought all I would have to do is include the A.pxi in B.pxi, which built fine.

Now, in my main Tester.py file I have

```
#import Project.Globals
#import Project.Utilies

someVar=Project.Globals.A.SomeFunction()
B.AnotherFunction(someVar)
```

The python debugger is telling me "in Another Function, received Project.Globals.A, expected Project.Utilities.A

I know why the error is, because I included the pxi file, and cython wrote A as a portion of it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against my desk for several hours, I FINALLY figured it out.  I read the manual in depth about the proper way to build a module.

1. C / C++ codes (cppclass) belong in a .pxd file
2. Python wrapper classes belong in a .pyx file,that contains

> cimport myCFile

which is the corresponding pxd file

3. An `__init__.py` file (can be empty) belongs in EVERY directory
4. place a "." in the include path directory, and make everything relative to that.

It works beautifully!